# Apache Oozie workflows

Tags: python, hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am new to Oozie. I have couple of questions on oozie job scheduling.

1. Can we get a list of jobs which scheduled on ozzie server for everyday run using some programmatic approach? Considering there are multiple job scheduled to run everyday may be for next couple of months or year.
2. How to know programmatically that a scheduled job had failed to run at day end for reporting purpose?
3. Can we do a ranking on oozie scheduled job on the basis of their execution time?

Thanks much for any help on this.

Comment: Oozie has a REST API. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cloudera Hue or Apache Ambari tools that will give you your all info about the Ozzie

If you are looking for more you can write you own program using some api expose by oozie.